# Gradle issue Error running Gradle: and FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I need help to resolve ***Gradle issue in the flutter***.

Here is the **error**:

```
*Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Users/abc/Workspace/kale-

flutter/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/dynamicProfile, src/dynamicProfile/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/dynamicProfile, src/nullnullDynamicProfile]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/profile, src/profile/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/profile, src/nullnullProfile]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/dynamicRelease, src/dynamicRelease/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/dynamicRelease, src/nullnullDynamicRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/abc/Workspace/kale-flutter/android/build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'get' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Command: /Users/abc/Workspace/kale-flutter/android/gradlew app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I am not able to solve this issue. Need an expert advice for working solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi! Adding details of your project and what you expect may help everyone to understand and help you

Comment: i think that first error is regarding to firebase and googl sign in. i think that you are using fire base or googl sign in in you project but forgot to add google-services.json file or you added at wrong place insted of src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the error will occur when you are using any type of service related to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and you have not put the *google-services.json* file in a proper location which we needed to use the service. Check out the screenshot from Firebase:

[image]

The `google-services.json` file should be placed in the `app/` directory (*at the root of the Android Studio app module*).

See also official guideline about [Adding the JSON](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).